# Magento google adwords - Track transaction-specific conversion values

Tags: google-ads-api, magento-1.8

i need to add the below code in my success.phtml page , for track the conversion value.

Can anyone help me to modify the PHP code to make it work on Magento 1.8?

```
<!-- Google Code for Purchase Conversion Page -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
    /* <![CDATA[ */
    var google_conversion_id = 1234567890;
    var google_conversion_language = "en";
    var google_conversion_format = "1";
    var google_conversion_color = "666666";
    var google_conversion_label = "xxxxXXx1xXXX123X1xX";
    var google_conversion_value = 1.00;


    if (<? echo $totalValue ?>) {
        var google_conversion_value = <? echo $totalValue ?>;
        var google_conversion_currency = <? echo $currency ?>;
    }


    var google_conversion_currency = "USD";
        var google_remarketing_only = false;
    /* ]]> */ 
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
    src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js">
    </script>
    <noscript>
        <div style="display:inline;">
    <img height="1" width="1" style="border-style:none;" alt=""
    src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/
    conversion/1234567890/?value=


    <? echo $totalValue ?>&amp;currency_code=<? echo $currency ?>


    &amp;label=xxxxXXx1xXXX123X1xX&amp;guid=ON&amp;script=0">
        </div>
    </noscript>
    </body>
```

thank you

best regards

Emanuele

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to work with the below to pass the order value into the AdWords conversion tracking code:

```
/app/design/frontend/package/theme/template/checkout/success.phtml

$order_details = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId(Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId());
$adwords_transval = $order_details->subtotal_incl_tax;

<!-- snip -->
var google_conversion_id = 123456789;
var google_conversion_language = "en";
var google_conversion_format = "3";
var google_conversion_color = "ffffff";
var google_conversion_label = "Xw17CLqRyXIQ5NvqzgM";
var google_conversion_value = 0;
if (<?php echo $adwords_transval; ?>) {
    google_conversion_value = <?php echo $adwords_transval; ?>;
}
var google_conversion_currency = "GBP";
var google_remarketing_only = false;
<!-- /snip -->
```

You might have to tweak it depending on your tax set up...